# Can I use the module structure (collapse Java package paths) for the Project Pane -> Changed Files view in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I use the "Project Pane -> Project" view in IntelliJ, my Java package paths are collapsed based on the Modules in my Project Structure (e.g. com.company.project). I would like to use IntelliJ for code reviews, so I've checked out the changes locally and am looking at the "Project Pane -> Changed Files" view, but this doesn't pick up the project structure, so each folder takes an extra line. Can I get the best of both worlds here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out with the help of this answer about expanding the folders (which I also wanted to do) [How to expand folded package chain in Intellij IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001171/how-to-expand-folded-package-chain-in-intellij-idea)

Right click on "1:Project" to see the options for the project pane and then check "Flatten Packages".