# How to disable subfolder grouping in IntelIJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Sorry for bothering with stupid questions, but how can I disable directory subfolders grouping? Every time when I'm creating directory with sub folders thay are grouped in one line(see screen).
[Directory screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtvOh.png)
Thank you for answers.

Comment: In case this ever gets reopened, it's a duplicate of this [more fleshed out question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001171/how-to-expand-folded-package-chain-in-intellij-idea/22001294).

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:

1. Click on gear settings icon near project tree
2. Uncheck Compact middle packages option
3. Enjoy
   [Settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdbQZ.png)